# What will happen to the tropical rainforest when climate increases by 5°C?

Tags: climate-change, climate

Today's most likely outcome regarding climate change is between +3°C and +6°C. My guess is at least +5°C. Has anybody found some papers indicating the average increase at the equator and a prognosis about plant growth there?

Comment: This is a large area of research. There are many papers on the subject. What has your research so far shown?

Comment: It largely depends on where the rainforest is, so as it it is the is both too broad and you should show some sign of trying to find the answer on your own.

Comment: I have the impression that most papers deal with water transport. However plant growth is not just dependent on water. This paper seems to evaluate a C4 plant: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212094715300116. C4 plants are more heat resistant.